# Unexpected Error: (void-function check-calendar-holidays) in Calendar mode

Tags: calendar, diary

I am trying to adapt this code from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiaryMode for use in Emacs with calendar and diary.

```
(defun diary-schedule (m1 d1 y1 m2 d2 y2 dayname)
      "Entry applies if date is between dates on DAYNAME.  
    Order of the parameters is M1, D1, Y1, M2, D2, Y2 if
    `european-calendar-style' is nil, and D1, M1, Y1, D2, M2, Y2 if
    `european-calendar-style' is t. Entry does not apply on a history."
      (let ((date1 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
                    (if european-calendar-style
                        (list d1 m1 y1)
                      (list m1 d1 y1))))
            (date2 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
                    (if european-calendar-style
                        (list d2 m2 y2)
                      (list m2 d2 y2))))
            (d (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date)))
        (if (and 
             (<= date1 d) 
             (<= d date2)
             (= (calendar-day-of-week date) dayname)
             (not (check-calendar-holidays date))
             )
             entry)))
```

The above allows recurring items having entries like `&%%(diary-schedule 22 4 2003 1 8 2003 2) 18:00 History`.

I prefer ISO date format, so I would like to be able to enter in `~/.emacs.d/diary` entries like

```
%%(diary-schedule 2021 08 30 2021 12 10 1) 08:30 Recurring event
```

Accordingly, I have modified the aforementioned code thus:

```
(defun diary-schedule (y1 m1 d1 y2 m2 d2 weekday)
    ""
        (let ((date1 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
                 (diary-make-date y1 m1 d1)))
              (date2 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
                 (diary-make-date y2 m2 d2)))
              (d (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date)))
        (if (and 
            (<= date1 d) 
            (<= d date2)
            (= (calendar-day-of-week date) weekday)
        (not (check-calendar-holidays date))
        )
            entry)))
```

and I set `calendar-date-style` to `'iso`. However, when in Calendar mode, and I try to view diary for a given date (by pressing "d"), if there is a diary entry using `diary-schedule`, I get an error

```
Error (diary): Bad diary sexp at line 36 in ~/.emacs.d/diary:
(diary-schedule 2021 08 31 2021 12 10 2)
Error: (void-function check-calendar-holidays)
```

If I comment out the one line

```
(not (check-calendar-holidays date))
```

everything works OK.

`.emacs` includes the lines

```
(require 'calendar)

(setq calendar-date-style 'iso)
```

before the code above.

It seems that `check-calendar-holidays` should return a list of holidays that match `date` or `nil` otherwise. It also seems that `check-calendar-holidays` gets its input from `date` and that date style shouldn't matter. Perhaps I'm mistaken.

I used `M-: (setq calendar-debug-sexp t) RET` and then tried, so here is stack trace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function check-calendar-holidays)
  (check-calendar-holidays date)
  (not (check-calendar-holidays date))
  (and (<= date1 d) (<= d date2) (= (calendar-day-of-week date) weekday) (not (check-calendar-holidays date)))
  (if (and (<= date1 d) (<= d date2) (= (calendar-day-of-week date) weekday) (not (check-calendar-holidays date))) entry)
  (let ((date1 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (diary-make-date y1 m1 d1))) (date2 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian (diary-make-date y2 m2 d2))) (d (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date))) (if (and (<= date1 d) (<= d date2) (= (calendar-day-of-week date) weekday) (not (check-calendar-holidays date))) entry))
  diary-schedule(2021 8 31 2021 12 10 2)
  eval((diary-schedule 2021 8 31 2021 12 10 2))
  diary-sexp-entry("(diary-schedule 2021 08 31 2021 12 10 2)" "10:15 Recurring appointment" (9 7 2021))
  diary-list-sexp-entries((9 7 2021))
  diary-list-entries((9 7 2021) 1)
  diary-view-entries(1)
  funcall-interactively(diary-view-entries 1)
  call-interactively(diary-view-entries nil nil)
  command-execute(diary-view-entries)
```

`Symbol's function definition is void: check-calendar-holidays` appears in the minibuffer.

New to Emacs and not sure how to debug. Why do I get this error?

Comment: Because the function is called `calendar-check-holidays`. Apparently the wiki page is very old, and the name was different, but at some point all calendar functions were renamed with the `calendar-` prefix.

Comment: I fixed the name on the wiki page.

Comment: I did some spelunking with git on the emacs sources: the renaming happened and compatibility aliases were added in 2007. The aliases were removed in 2014. You found this on the wiki in 2021. I predict that the next time that this problem will pop up will be in 2028.

Comment: `calendar-check-holidays` works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pursuant to [@NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd)'s most helpful comments, the issue was indeed that `check-calendar-holidays` is no more and `calendar-check-holidays` is now the correct function, hence:

```
(defun diary-schedule (y1 m1 d1 y2 m2 d2 weekday &optional mark)
"Assumes calendar-date-style = iso.
Entry applies if date is between date1 and date2 
and on the specified weekday, e.g., monday = 1.
Note: Expected order of parameters passed to 
diary-make-date depends on calendar-date-style."
(with-no-warnings (defvar date) (defvar entry))
(let ((date1 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
         (diary-make-date y1 m1 d1)))
      (date2 (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
         (diary-make-date y2 m2 d2)))
      (d (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian date)))
(and 
    (<= date1 d) 
    (<= d date2)
    (= (calendar-day-of-week date) weekday)
    (not (calendar-check-holidays date))
    (cons mark entry))))
```

Comment: You should [accept](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) your answer - assuming that it answered your question :-)